# Props that are sent to another component using React Router show up as undefined and as [object%20Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Using ReactJS and React Router, I'm trying to send what someone writes in the search bar to another component. I have tried passing an object in a React link, but it's not working for some reason. In the directed component it shows as undefined and in the url it says `/search/[object%20Object]`.

The code below is in the search component where the `searchValue` is what the user has inputted. The `searchValue` does hold the correct value till this point.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/search/" + { searchValue },
    state: { sentinfo: searchValue },
  }}
```

and this is how I try to read the props in the component I've sent it to:

```
const { foo } = this.props.location.state;
console.log(foo);
```

It shows `undefined` here. I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Is this just a typo? You send it as `location.state.sentinfo` but try to access it via `location.state.foo`? `foo` will OFC be undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm trying to access it through location.state.foo, does the const need to be the same name as the state I'm trying to access? can you please clarify?

Comment: You made it an object. It should be: `pathname: "/search/" + searchValue`

Comment: @Sodaxi, `const {foo} = obj` means, you are destructuring foo from obj.  foo has to be in obj otherwise foo will be null. try console.log(this.props.location.state) itself and see the obj structure

Comment: I got it now. I'm just pretty new to all of this so I'm still trying to get the gist of it. thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have passing the object into the url

```
<Link
to={{
pathname: "/search/" + { searchValue },
state: { sentinfo: searchValue },
}}/>
```

pass it in JSX format

```
  <Link
    to={{
    pathname: `/search/${searchValue}`,
    state: { sentinfo: searchValue },
    }}/>
```

and then you can use the sentinfo as

const foo = this.props.location.state.sentinfo;

as per my suggesstion you are already passing the searchValue into the url so their is no need for passing the same value into the state.You can access the url parameter using this `this.props.match.params` syntax.